# How to make VNC Server work with ubuntu-desktop without xfce

Tags: server, 14.04, xfce, vnc

I have Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 and I want to know whether it's possible to install vnc4server and make it work with ubuntu-desktop (and not xubuntu-desktop) without installing xfce4.

I think I have to configure the vnc4server configuration file but I'm a beginner with all this.

Please, don't suggest that I use xrdp or gnome-core. I just want to run a VNC Server using only the original ubuntu-desktop installation. I use VNC Viewer to connect to my servers, but I don't have any problem with suggestions that I use something different than vnc4server if it's going to work with ubuntu-desktop.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

install these packages

```
# apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

and use this xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Comment: I said that I want to run the VNC via the original ubuntu-desktop, does what you suggested run with ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: those are just gnome packages to help vnc4server load properly or else you wont see your desktop correctly

Comment: Awesome....been searching for ages and this worked like a charm!!

Comment: Desktop is up (which is great), but Unity launcher & keyboard shortcuts doesn't work ...

Comment: Yup, no unity love following these directions. (sadface) just a plain gnome desktop

Comment: Works very bad with a lot of garbage

Comment: Found this post coming from [setting up tightVNC](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04) but wanted to use gnome desktop instead. Much thanks

Answer (score 10):

I had to add `gnome-session &` prior to `gnome-panel &` to get any window management to work. Without it, I could only view the default desktop.