# Unity doesn't work on VNC server under 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, 14.04, vnc

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I find the Unity destkop in vnc4server never works as it did under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is my ~/.vnc/xstartup for vnc4server:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

/usr/bin/gnome-session &
```

That works fine starting Unity desktop on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but unfortunately on 14.04 LTS only a gray screen is seen in vncviewer.

I searched a little and find [this article](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html) shows the way to start legacy gnome desktop (gnome-fallback) in vnc on 14.04, but what I want is the solution for a normal Unity desktop in vnc.

Has anyone successfully run Unity desktop in a vnc session (vnc4server, or any other vnc server) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Might be irrelevant: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers I am running a desktop version and recently upgraded to 16.04. Stock Vino works well

Answer (score 9):

This [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/475036/283933) link shows the solution.

Install these packages:

```
apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

Use this `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using the gnome-fallback desktop environment, the proper xstartup file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

/usr/bin/autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork

gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback --disable-acceleration-check &
```

For the clipboard sync to work correctly you also need to install autocutsel:

```
sudo apt-get install autocutsel
```

Don't forget to restart TightVNC Server:

```
vncserver -kill :1
vncserver
```

Good luck!