# How to setup ~/.vnc/xstartup/ with Unity as Desktop, in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: unity, 14.10, vnc

I used to setup my xstartup like this in Ubuntu 12.04 as below and it worked fine.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &

export DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu-2d
export GDMSESSION=ubuntu-2d
export STARTUP="/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d"

$STARTUP
```

But now I transfered to Ubuntu 14.10, but what I've got is only a dark desktop with only a gnome-terminal. Under /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/, there are no longer ubuntu-2d.session, but only ubuntu.session now. So I changed the 3 ubuntu-2d to ubuntu, but still the same situation. Anyone got any idea how to fix this?

PS: I don't want to use gnome-desktop, I just want to use unity... That's the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing for unity on 15.04 but so far all I can get is a blank screen in VNC

Comment: For 14.04, installing metacity, uncommenting x-window-manager, and removing --session from gnome-session worked. For 15.04, the same thing resulted in a blank gray screen.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me to get my Ubuntu back:

[Unity doesn't work on VNC server under 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518041/unity-doesnt-work-on-vnc-server-under-14-04-lts/820171)

I still have a few things to get back, like the launch bar that was on the left, but I thought this might help you if you are still looking. :)