# How to setup remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, sharing

I have 2 Ubuntu 14.04 machines running the default Ubuntu desktop, I only have a monitor for one so I'm trying to setup remote desktop on the machine without a monitor. How can I setup the non-monitor computer to accept VNC connections from my computer with a monitor?
**I tried X11 forwarding over terminal, didn't work. Don't care about X11 forwarding as long as i can access the other with built in remote desktop client.
***Also if possible how can I do remote desktop with 2 Xubuntu machines?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the suggestion here: [How to make VNC Server work with ubuntu-desktop without xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce) to see if that does what you need.