# How To Start VNC Session With Gnome Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to start a `VNC session` with the `Gnome Desktop` as follows:

**Server Side**

Configure `.vnc/xstartup` file to:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

`vnc4server` start a session on the **server**:

```
selenium@selenium-grid:~$ vnc4server -geometry 1024x768 :1

New 'selenium-grid:1 (selenium)' desktop is selenium-grid:1

Starting applications specified in /home/selenium/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/selenium/.vnc/selenium-grid:1.log
```

Start a new section of `xvnc4viewer` on the **client side**:

```
 $ xvnc4viewer <IP my server>:<Port my server>
```

**Result:**

[image]

I'm trying to start a `VNC session` with the `Gnome Desktop` with the following settings and commands:

Kill the session of `vnc4server` on the **server side**:

```
selenium@selenium-grid:~$ vnc4server -kill :1
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 10747
```

edit `.vnc/xstartup` file to on the **server side**:

```
$ sudo nano .vnc/xstartup
```

**Edited file:**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
/usr/bin/gnome-session &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
# x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &
```

Start a new session of `vnc4server` in **server**

```
selenium@selenium-grid:~$ vnc4server -geometry 1024x768 :1

New 'selenium-grid:1 (selenium)' desktop is selenium-grid:1

Starting applications specified in /home/selenium/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/selenium/.vnc/selenium-grid:1.log
```

**Client side**

```
$ xvnc4viewer <IP my server>:<Port my server>
```

**Result:**
[image]

Because my `Gnome Desktop` session is not appearing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was also unable to do this with Gnome. Switching to XFCE or KDE worked.

Comment: This [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce) helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

install these packages:

```
apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

use this startup file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get full featured gnome desktop with tigervnc (following this guide https://www.teknotut.com/en/install-vnc-server-with-gnome-display-on-ubuntu-18-04/)