# Connecting to Ubuntu server on AWS EC2 - grey screen for desktop

Tags: 14.04, vnc

I have fired up on AWS EC2 a Ubuntu instance.

Result of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I referred to [how to make vnc server work with Ubuntu desktop without xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce?answertab=active#tab-top) so that I could logon via VNC Client to my Ubuntu desktop. I can still only see a grey screen.

This is how my `vnc/xstartup` file looks.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
  unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

  export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
  unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

  [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
  [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
  xsetroot -solid grey
  vncconfig -iconic &

  metacity &
  gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-session &
  gnome-panel &

  nautilus &
  gnome-terminal &

# x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
# x-window-manager &
```

Any suggestions?

I apologize in advance if I have broken any community rules by posting this question as a new question instead of a follow up to the earlier thread. I shall move it there if you think it appropriate.