# Intel graphics drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS affect vnc client: does not start Unity desktop

Tags: unity, launcher, intel-graphics, vnc

I have a default Ubuntu 16.04.02 desktop installation.

Only additional installed software are openssh-server and Tigervnc

RealVNC viewer works fine from a windows machine, with the Unity desktop appearing on login.

**PROBLEM**: I installed Intel Graphics drivers 2.02 on the machine using Intel Graphics Update Tool and restarted.

Now, when I login to the machine from Windows via RealVNC, the Unity desktop does not appear. I get the wallpaper and the rightclick menu works to open a terminal, but no launcher, panel etc...

This article helped somewhat but is geared to 14.04 and does not launch the up-to-date unity desktop on the client:
[How to make VNC Server work with ubuntu-desktop without xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce/475036#475036)

I, too, do not want to use xfce4.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link which seems to work ok when I upgraded to 17.04. Some problems (noted in link). Also several options missing from desktop (e.g. certain settings)

https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/08/28/ubuntu-16-04-remote-connect-to-unity-with-vnc-xrdp/