# vnc service for ubuntu 18.04, no background and menus

Tags: 18.04, vnc, tightvncserver

There are many topics about accessing a remote desktop via vnc. However, it seems that 18.04 is different. I have installed `tightvncserver` and the content of `~/.vnc/xstartup` according to this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475023/how-to-make-vnc-server-work-with-ubuntu-desktop-without-xfce?answertab=active#tab-top) is

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

As I connect, I see an incomplete desktop without any background and system menu. There is no terminal also. See the picture

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this problem (with LXDE & lxpanel) long time ago.
It causes by panel start before the X display on VNCserver.

try delay gnome-panel by create 'gnome-panel-delay' script on same /usr/bin with following

## !/bin/sh

sleep 4 && gnome-panel

exec gnome-panel-delay instead of gnome-panel in ~/.vnc/xstartup or setting under ~/.config

Comment: Does not work... see the same thing as the original post.